# How can I count the rows with data in an Excel sheet?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to count the number of rows in a spreadsheet which contain at least one non-blank value over a few columns: i.e.

```
row 1 has a text value in column A
row 2 has a text value in column B
row 3 has a text value in column C
row 4 has no values in A, B or C
```

The formula would equate to 3, because rows 1, 2, & 3 have a text value in at least one column. Similarly if row 1 had a text value in each column (A, B, & C) this would be counted as 1.

Answer (score 21):

With formulas, what you can do is:

- in a new column (say col D - cell `D2`), add `=COUNTA(A2:C2)`
- drag this formula till the end of your data (say cell `D4` in our example)
- add a last formula to sum it up (e.g in cell `D5`): `=SUM(D2:D4)`

Comment: +1, The key function here is COUNTA (note the A at the end), which counts cells that contain data.

Comment: For anyone who doesn't know the row count or wants it to be variable, just type in the whole column: `=COUNTA(A:A)`, assuming the column only contains cells you want to count and nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a simple one liner that will do it all for you (assuming by no value you mean a blank cell):

```
=(ROWS(A:A) + ROWS(B:B) + ROWS(C:C)) - COUNTIF(A:C, "")
```

If by no value you mean the cell contains a 0

```
=(ROWS(A:A) + ROWS(B:B) + ROWS(C:C)) - COUNTIF(A:C, 0)
```

The formula works by first summing up all the rows that are in columns A, B, and C (if you need to count more rows, just increase the columns in the range. E.g. `ROWS(A:A) + ROWS(B:B) + ROWS(C:C) + ROWS(D:D) + ... + ROWS(Z:Z)`).

Then the formula counts the number of values in the same range that are blank (or 0 in the second example).

Last, the formula subtracts the total number of cells with no value from the total number of rows. This leaves you with the number of cells in each row that contain a value

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind VBA, here is a function that will do it for you. Your call would be something like:

```
=CountRows(1:10)
```

```vb
Function CountRows(ByVal range As range) As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim row As range
Dim count As Long

For Each row In range.Rows
    If (Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(row)) - 256 <> 0 Then
        count = count + 1
    End If
Next

CountRows = count
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Function
```

How it works: I am exploiting the fact that there is a 256 row limit. The worksheet formula CountBlank will tell you how many cells in a row are blank. If the row has no cells with values, then it will be 256. So I just minus 256 and if it's not 0 then I know there is a cell somewhere that has some value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this scenario:

Array = `A1:C7`. `A1-A3` have values, `B2-B6` have value and `C1`, `C3` and `C6` have values.

To get a count of the number of rows add a column `D` (you can hide it after formulas are set up) and in `D1` put formula `=If(Sum(A1:C1)>0,1,0)`. Copy the formula from `D1` through `D7` (for others searching who are not excel literate, the numbers in the sum formula will change to the row you are on and this is fine).

Now in `C8` make a sum formula that adds up the `D` column and the answer should be `6`. For visually pleasing purposes hide column `D`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the sumif function in Excel:

`=SUMIF(A5:C10;"Text_to_find";C5:C10)`

This function takes a range like this square A5:C10 then you have some text to find this text can be in A or B then it will add the number from the C-row.

Comment: This only works if the text matches. What if the person is just dealing with emails that are unique, or names? Or is just trying to find the number of cells with and without non-unified data?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I finally came up with, which works great!

`{=SUM(IF((ISTEXT('Worksheet Name!A:A))+(ISTEXT('CCSA Associates'!E:E)),1,0))-1}`

Don't forget since it is an array to type the formula above without the "{}", and to CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER instead of just ENTER for the "{}" to appear and for it to be entered properly.